# How to save and retrieve binary image data to picture box in winforms using C#

Tags: sql, image, winforms, picturebox, image-uploading

How to save and retrieve binary image data to picture box in Winforms using C#?

I have tried this

```
ms = new MemoryStream();
pictureBox1.Image.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
byte[] photo_aray = new byte[ms.Length];
ms.Position = 0;
ms.Read(photo_aray, 0, photo_aray.Length);

SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("insert into Registration(Photo)values('"+photo_aray+"')
```

It is saving but when trying to retrieve, an error "parameter is invalid" is showing up.

I have tried this for search

```
photo_aray = (byte[])dr[0];
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(photo_aray);
pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromStream(ms);
```

in the last line I am getting error, how to sort this? My database column for `Photo` is `Image`

Comment: Can you update the question with error message?

Comment: What is the datatype of the column PHOTO on your DataTable Registration? Are you using an nvarchar to store binary data?

Comment: `ntext`, `text`, and `image` data types will be removed in a future version of SQL Server. Avoid using these data types in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use them. Use `nvarchar(max)`, `varchar(max)`, and `varbinary(max)` instead. [See details here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx)

Comment: @Steve my data type in sql server is image type

Answer (score 2):

First thing to be sure. Your column `PHOTO` should be declared as `varbinary(MAX)` in your table.
This is the recommended datatype to store binary values.

Now to save your PictureBox image you need a sligthly different code:

```
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
pictureBox1.Image.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
byte[] imgData = new byte[ms.Length];
ms.Position = 0;
ms.Read(imgData, 0, imgData.Length);

// Using a parameterized query passing the binary data as binary not as chars...
string cmdText = "INSERT INTO Registration(Photo) VALUES (@picBits)";
using(SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(......))
using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(cmdText, con)) 
{ 
con.Open(); 
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter {ParameterName = "@picBits", 
                                        SqlDbType = SqlDbType.VarBinary, 
                                        Size = imgData.Length,
                                        Value = imgData});
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

To reload your image from the database inside the PictureBox you need something like this

```
byte[] imgData;

// Of course this command should be adapted to your context
string cmdText = "SELECT Photo from Registration where id = 1";

using(SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(.....))
using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(cmdText, con)) 
{ 
   con.Open(); 
   using(SqlDataReader reader = pvCommand.ExecuteReader())
   {
       if(reader.Read())
       {
           // First call to get the length of binary data that we want to read back
           long bufLength = reader.GetBytes(0, 0, null, 0, 0);

           // Now allocate a buffer big enough to receive the bits...
           imgData = new byte[bufLength];

           // Get all bytes from the reader
           reader.GetBytes(0,0,imgData, 0, (int)bufLength);

           // Transfer everything to the Image property of the picture box....
           MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(imgData);
           ms.Position = 0;
           pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromStream(ms);
       }    
   }
}
```