# Convert binary back to image

Tags: c#, linq, wcf

I have a wcf service and Windows Forms. I was able to convert an image to binary and store it to my EmpTable in sql server in varbinary(MAX) data type. I used linq and entity data model to access my tables. Now I am trying to display EmpTable to a DataGridView on my forms, and I noticed that it displays "System.byte[]" on the column. So when I tried to convert it back to image, it failed. Now I am clueless on how can I fetch the data and convert it back to image. All my linq commands are in my service and I am using it in my winforms. How can I do this?

Comment: have a look at [How to save and retrieve binary image data to picture box in WinForms using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27621794/2417602) and as for a better approach, it would be better to store the images in a separate folder and refer that path in the DB instead of `binary` data.

Comment: Set the Column of the DGV which receives the byte array as a `DataGridViewImageColumn`. It will handle the Image data on its own.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `MemoryStream` to convert the `byte[]` to image:

```
var bytes = getBytes();     // get bytes from db
Image img;
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(bytes))
{
    img = Image.FromStream(ms);
}
```

To save the image to the DataGrid set the image column to `DataGridViewImageColumn`:

```
DataGridViewImageColumn imgGrd = new DataGridViewImageColumn();
imgGrd.Image = img;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here function to convert from `byte[]` to `BitmapImage`.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Convert byte[] to bitmapimage
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="array"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static BitmapImage byteArrayToImage(byte[] array)
    {
        if (array != null)
        {
            using (var ms = new MemoryStream(array))
            {
                var image = new BitmapImage();
                image.BeginInit();
                image.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
                image.StreamSource = ms;
                image.EndInit();
                return image;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```